# Github for mac diff options

Tags: git, github, diff, github-for-mac

Is there a way to configure [github for mac](http://mac.github.com/) to do a diff with the `-w` option to ignore whitespace?

We are in the process of replacing all tabs with spaces in our project but when looking at the diffs for these commits in Github:mac the whole file is marked as changed which makes it hard to see the actual changes.

Comment: Did you email their support? <support@github.com>  I did.  Will post back with their response...

Comment: You ever end up getting a response, @alexgray?

Comment: I asked support at github.com about this today, and pointed them to this question. Josh at github.com replied today, and said that they had had other requests for this, and they'd add my plea to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have "actual" changes mingled in with the tab changes?  Stash your current work, do one giant sweep to clean up the whitespace, push that, then go back to your regularly scheduled programming.  Sure, you'll hit a few merge conflicts with anything you were working on before the whitespace fix, but that's unavoidable.